# Are uploaded images hosted forever irrespective of usage?

Tags: support, images

**Case 1:**
I'm asking a question, I need to add few images with that. I've added 5 images, and posted my question, after some time, I feel that three of the images doesn't need to add, so do I edited the question and remove (those image URLs) from question.

- How this change will affect on server? Will server remove those images later time? Is there any mechanism for this? Or those images will never get remove?

**Case 2:**
While asking a question (before posting) I've uploaded 5 images, while writing I'll remove all uploaded images URLs and will only post the question.

- What will happen to those images? How server maintaining this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Based on the fact that [StackExchange has a network-wide "pro" account with Imgur](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/new-image-upload-support/) (only when uploading through the native uploader), images are meant to hang around indefinitely.

So, in either case you mention, the images should remain. If they are removed from the post via an edit, the revision history will contain those images.

Related post on [Meta.SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com): [Can I / should I delete unused images from Imgur?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/94710/168244)